# How to cancel local port forward from ssh console

Tags: ssh

I can forward local ports using the command below

```
ssh> help
Commands:
      -L[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request local forward
      -R[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request remote forward
      -KR[bind_address:]port                 Cancel remote forward

ssh> -L 8080:localhost:8080
Forwarding port.
```

But how to cancel that port forward? I see the -KR for cancel remote forwards but there does not appear to be a -KL to cancel my local forward.

Asking for another forward on the same port (hoping to override the old one) gives this message

```
ssh> -L 8080:localhost:8081
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 10101
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with more recent versions of (open)ssh, there's an escape command to cancel local forwards as well:

```
ssh> help
Commands:
      -L[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request local forward
      -R[bind_address:]port:host:hostport    Request remote forward
      -D[bind_address:]port                  Request dynamic forward
      -KL[bind_address:]port                 Cancel local forward
      -KR[bind_address:]port                 Cancel remote forward
      -KD[bind_address:]port                 Cancel dynamic forward
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no simple way to do it on the command-line.

You can find the PID:

```
$ ps x | grep ssh
 1234 ?        Ss     0:00 ssh -f -N -L 8080:localhost:8080 remotehost
```

And then kill the process:

```
$ kill 1234
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no way other than to exit the connection and start over. I'd love to be proven wrong...

Comment: Changed accepted answer due to updates in openssh